# How to decrease memory used by Rscript.exe?

Tags: r

In RStudio, I'm using the package `parallel` to create a cluster of 3 cores on my 4core 8GB RAM machine and run `parLapply`. The Rscript.exe spawned goes from 1+GB suddenly to 3GB and Physical memory used becomes 99%. My machine freezes and I cannot kill the process.

How do I decrease the memory used?

Methods I've seen include:

- In a .Rprofile in the working directory, set R_MAX_MEM_SIZE=4096M.
  memory.limit() still returns 8067.
- Add an argument --max-mem-size=4096M to the Rgui.exe when starting
  it. But I'm using RStudio.

### Update (in case anyone lands here with the same issue)

As per comments below, it's not possible. To circumvent the event of a frozen machine, I ran the code in a virtual machine instead -- then you can use `type='FORK'`, and also limit the memory used by the vm. If the vm crashes (linux actually automatically kills processes when it's low in memory), you can just open a new instance.

Comment: Could you please clarify? You were using 1G and then split to 3 cores and started seeing 3G? Sounds like its working as intended and unless you reduce that 1G one single core it will continue to triple when you go to 3 cores

Comment: try shutting off all other applications, and if you can unload all packages that you are not going to use on your script. Also if possible, execute the script directly from command line instead of starting Rstudio to save ram

Comment: @JustGettinStarted memory.limit() is 8067. The cluster spawns 3 Rscript processes. One of the Rscript processes goes up to 3gb.

Comment: Read the [vignette of package parallel](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/doc/parallel.pdf) carefully, some things are simply not possible on Windows as the (POSIX) function `fork()` is offered by the OS.  So IIRC complete new R processes are started via a socket cluster -- and that is expensive.  See the vignette for details.

Comment: In short, buy more RAM.